# XPath element select

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select an `i` element as follows:

```
//div[contains(text(), "daddsadas@lol.com")]//parent//i[contains(@class, "fa fa-pencil")]
```

From the following HTML:

```
<td ng-class="{true:'disable'}[contact.status=='deactive']">
  <div class="email ng-binding">daddsadas@lol.com</div>
    <div class="name">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="ng-binding">
              Test Last
            </td>
            <td>
              <i class="fa fa-pencil" ng-click="display_edit_contact_form(contact)"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-trash" ng-click="delete_contact(contact)"></i>
            </td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
  </div>
</td>
```

I cannot seem to get it to work. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually avoid traversing the tree, going up and down by using [`following`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following):

```
//div[. = "daddsadas@lol.com"]/following::i[contains(@class, "fa-pencil")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve this by treating xpath queries the same as a file system:

```
//div[contains(text(), "daddsadas@lol.com")]/..//i[contains(@class, "fa-pencil")]
```